# Continuing issue with location simulator - non responsive to location change input

Tags: eclipse, geolocation, ios-simulator, codenameone, eclipse-mars

I have been having a running problem with the location simulator for the last couple of weeks.

When I enter updates of Latitude and Longitude, I note that they do not have any effect on the actual location. Similarly, when I try to drag the map to a new location, I don't see any response either. The hand cursor is no longer shown when the mouse cursor is over the map. An I-Beam cursor appears, instead.

Also, the zoom buttons are no longer shown so it's not clear how to zoom in and out on the map.

I had filed this issue in a different Stack Overflow question. I got some responses, which turned out to not be sufficient to solve the problem.
Unfortunately, I then had to deal with an unrelated issue and was away for a couple of weeks. When I returned, I downloaded the latest build and tried the simulator.

I noticed that several changes were in place in the location simulator, including being able to enter a new latitude, longitude, velocity, etc. Also, the Update button was no longer present. However, the same issue was present where none of the changes had any effect on the actual location shown in the simulator.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there is still a bug in CN1.
Since I don't hear a lot of other people grousing about this issue, I'm guessing it's some configuration or installation problem on my system. However, I have not had any response to my comments or questions on Stack Overflow.

I wonder if there is a particular version of Java now needed to run CN1 on eclipse Mars? I updated Java to version SDK 1.8.0_77, which appears to be the most current version according to java.com. I restarted eclipse and found that it and CN1 seem to run okay. In the location simulator, I see no change to the behavior at issue. Location UI still does not accept user input

Since I have a Professional CN1 license, this is the only help/support available. I can't afford the Enterprise license. The turnaround time on any questions/responses appears to be about a day, due to the time difference (Tel Aviv vs Minneapolis).

I added a reply several days ago now on my previous thread on this issue and never got a reply. So I am starting a new thread. Hopefully that will get some attention.

This issue is becoming a real roadblock to my getting work completed. I note you talk about how your updates are making CN1 easier to use. So far this has nothing but frustration - end of vent... :-)

```
Essential Stats:
IDE: Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Desktop OS: Windows 8.1
Using Simulator
```

Thank you,
 -Craig Lang,
  Horizon Technologies

Comment: Ran CN1 simulator in debug mode and found null pointer exception when I tried to drag the map:

Exception in runnable
java.lang.NullPointerException: Clipboard.putContent: null data
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.putContent (Unknown Source)
 ... [lots more stuff in stack trace] ...

Comment: Okay - Got it!!!! I was right. it was a configuration problem. I was using jdk 1.8.0_77 as the Java.home. However, in the Run Configurations for the simulater, the JRE was set to JRE7. When I changed the configuration, I found the location simulator now allows me to drag the map. ----- Hope this can be a help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the exception you got but I think we do need to put out a warning when running under JDK 7. We'll look into that.